# Method not allowed error for GraphQL requests with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql, spring-graphql

I have a Java Spring web server that I want to force to use Spring's GraphQL library over GraphQL's own Java library so that I can manage the access to individual queries/mutations.

After following a [guide online](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current/reference/html/) on how to do that, I have the following dependencies in my `pom.xml`:

```xml
...
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.3</version>
</parent>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the simple controller I set up

```java
@Controller
public class GraphQLController {

    private MyObject obj;

    public GraphQLController(MyObject obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @SchemaMapping
    public Query query(){
        return new Query(obj);
    }

    @SchemaMapping
    public Mutation mutation(Path path){
        return new Mutation(obj, path);
    }
}
```

However, no matter the GraphQL request I am sending to the server, I always get the same response:

```json
{
  "timestamp": "2022-08-29T07:59:09.470+00:00",
  "status": 405,
  "error": "Method Not Allowed",
  "path": "/graphql"
}
```

I'm pasting here the properties file just in case.

```
graphql.servlet.corsEnabled=false
graphql.servlet.mapping=/graphql
```

I also tried using

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/graphql", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD, RequestMethod.PUT}, path = "/graphql",
        consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
class GraphQLController {...
```

but with no success.

```
# Schema
type Query{
    listProjects: [Project]
...
}

# Query I'm sending to localhost:8080/graphql
query {
    listProjects {
        name
    }
}
```

I'm no expert of Spring and this has been bugging me for the past couple of days, can anyone help?
Many thanks!

Comment: Can you please add more detail like - how are you executing the query, and what's the GraphQL schema? Also, you can check this article (with code example), if you want  - https://techdozo.dev/spring-for-graphql-schemamapping-and-querymapping/

Comment: @Pankaj thank you for the link, it's been very useful to understand how this works better. I added the details to the question. However, it seems to me that this is a permissions error, so maybe it has to do with some configuration or missing dependency (?).

Comment: When using Spring for GraphQL, you should not need the `@RequestMapping` on your `@Controller` class. Maybe that leads to conflicts, I'd remove that annotation. To configure the GraphQL path in your application.properties, you have to use `spring.graphql.path=/graphql` (but `/graphql` is also the default, so you don't have to set this). Can you elaborate how you send the query to the server? Are you sure, you're using an HTTP *POST* request? Also make sure, that your schema file is in a folder called `src/main/resources/graphql` and its name ends with `.graphqls`.

Comment: Thank you for your help @NilsHartmann. Indeed, the problem was that I had the schema file under `src/main/resources/`, instead of `src/main/resources/graphql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @NilsHartmann in the comments, the problem was that I had the schema file under `src/main/resources/` instead of `src/main/resources/graphql`.